# Echo a numerical value in query_posts

Tags: query-posts

I am creating an option page for one of my wordpress themes and I am trying to ask user to enter "Number of posts to show" -

I am using "query_posts" to show posts 
This is the code I modified but it is not working

`<?php query_posts("posts_per_page='".of_get_option('numberofposts', '3' )."'&cat='".of_get_option('postcategory', 'no entry' )."'"); while(have_posts()) : the_post();?>`

the correct method to echo the option used is :

`<?php echo of_get_option('numberofposts', 'no entry' ); ?>`

which returns a value the user entered - ex : 5

the category section works , I can output the category ID but not the number of posts .

thanks in advanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the value of posts per page in single quotes, remove the quotes and it will work.

That said, you should be altering the main query with [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) instead of `query_posts`.